# Get all members of Jira _not_ in a particular group

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

My overarching task is to get all members of Jira *except those* in a particular group, but I think I need some intermediary help before I can get there. I'm using jira-python, and I've gotten so far as to sort of get the group I need:

```
print jira.groups(query='jira-developers')
```

gives me

```
{u'header': u'Showing 1 of 1 matching groups', u'total': 1, u'groups': [{u'html': u'<b>jira-developers</b>', u'name': u'jira-developers'}]}
```

which was not the format I expected, but fine. I can't get the members of that group. The documentation seems to suggest that [jira.group_members(group)](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#jira.client.JIRA.group_members) should work, but I get the error that jira has no attribute group_members. Maybe I need to access the group differently?  But that error makes no sense to me based on the docs.

Comment: What version of JIRA are you using? That method is a JIRA 6.x method

Comment: 6.1.4 Jira, 0.16 jira-python

Comment: Is there a different/better way to get members of a group?

Comment: Not that I've found in the REST API sadly

Comment: Can you directly query the database?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I looked briefly at the jira-python documentation and it seems like they still don't do much of anything with groups or group membership. I ended up writing a short script using requests to hit the `group/member` JIRA REST API. Maybe this answer will provide a starting point to anyone finding this result in a search. I ended up making it a bit more complex than the simple example below by using recursion to handle the `nextPage` attribute when JIRA pages your results.

```
import requests
import json as JSON

JIRA_REST_URL = "http://jira.server.or.cloud.com/rest/api/2/"
JIRA_USERNAME = "agent007"
JIRA_PASSWORD = "secret"
HEADERS = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

session = requests.session()
session.auth = (JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD)
group_to_check = "some_group_name"
group_url = JIRA_REST_URL + "group/member?groupname=%s&includeInactiveUsers=false&maxResults=50"  % group_to_check

page = session.get(group_url, headers=HEADERS)
json_page = JSON.loads(page.text)
for each_value in json_page['values']:
    print each_value['displayName']
```